# VB.NET Application.Restart behaviour - unexpected result

Tags: .net, vb.net, auto-update

I have an application, foo.exe, with a built in updater. It will connect to a server and if there is an update, renames the current (running) application to foo.exe.bak, download foo.exe and call `Application.Restart` to start foo.exe which is now the new version. This seem to work... most of the time. One computer I run it on seems to always, and others occasionally, bring down the new version but still load the old version. Restarting the application through a button that calls `Application.Restart` then makes the correct version come up.

During this failed restart period, the file on the local system is 1.2, on the server is 1.2, but the running version is the 1.1 that we just updated. Since the updater got tweaked recently to allow for checking for DLL updates as well as the current executable version, it is now checking the version of the exe file (1.2) and not the version of the running application (1.1) against the expected version, so is not triggering another update due to the version mismatch. Ultimately this means that my application now has a wrong-side failure where it believes it is the updated version.

I had a 1 second delay prior to calling the restart. Increasing this to five has done nothing to correct the problem.
Is there something I am missing with regards to how `Application.Restart` works?
I tried `Shell(Application.ExecutablePath)` `Application.Exit` but that didn't work - all it did was make the application exit. Is there a reliable way to make my application close and start foo.exe again?

Thanks

Comment: Anti-malware is always around to give you a migraine.  They never much like an executable file appearing from seemingly nowhere.  The wonkier ones will take their merry time to scan, making it look like it isn't there yet.  But that can't easily explain why you can execute a .bak file.  Do make sure you yell loudly enough whenever any of these operations fail, including a case where the user account does not have sufficient right to rename or create a file in the install directory.  Which *is* the normal case, UAC protects c:\program files.

Comment: Did you try using `Process.Start()` on the file **foo.exe** and then from the (now) **foo.exe.bak** file simply exit?  Esentially, avoiding calling restart at all.  Also, probably a job for ClickOnce if possible.

Comment: Hans: On the device I'm having trouble with, the software is in c:\foo while I've been testing it - it hasn't been traditionally installed.
It is successfully renaming the file and downloads any new DLLs into that folder, plus the new executable. If it were a rights problem, I would expect those to fail as well. I will have a look at any anti-malware interactions. My first thought was that Application.Restart() may have been reloading the exact thing that was running, but that wouldn't explain it behaving on the second call - it should surely keep going.
Thanks

Comment: Jason: I will try that - I went with Shell for testing since I forgot the new way of doing that. If this doesn't work then I will look in to ClickOnce.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all of this, it was a timing problem. The application was getting ahead of itself, starting up as if there were no update required, then the updater was passing a message back saying "Hey guys! I've got an update!" by which time the application had already started.

Answer (score -1):

> renames the current (running) application to foo.exe.bak

How do you expect this is accomplished? Windows will not allow you to rename any program file while it's currently executing.

Most applications that want to do automatic updates will have a 2nd "updater" program to accomplish this, where the main program will start the updater program when it detects an update and then shut down. The updater program will wait until the main program exits, update anything that needs updating, restart the main program, and then quit.

I've also seen the main program be responsible for downloading "update" files, and then starting a quick .bat file before it quits where the batch file only renames things and then starts the program again.

But either way, if you're trying to update your *.exe file while that *.exe file is still running, you're gonna end up with strange results.

One other thing worth noting is that the Program Files folder by default is read-only for standard-privilege user accounts. If you need your end users to be able to update files in this folder, you need to change the default permissions on the folder during your original installation process.

Comment: It does allow it.  The MMF only puts a lock on the file data, not the directory entry.  And besides, if your guess were correct then he would have discovered that a long time ago.

Comment: I was shocked to find that one of the few things you CAN do to a running executable is rename it.